# Read Excel Numeric cell values

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I am reading excel numeric cell values, i am getting the output with decimals. eg: 4110515268 is reading as 4.110515268E9.Help me!
 This is my code:-

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\AMC test cases1.xls")); 
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Clinic Basic info");
 WebElement creat_new_website =driver.findElement(By.className("createnew"));
 creat_new_website.click();

 driver.findElement(By.id("primaryno_m")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(13).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()));
```

Comment: I think you need to add another tag to this question as this isn't excel formulae or Excel-VBA language

Comment: This looks more like C#.NET - can you please apply the correct tag for the programming language that you are using. Also if this is VSTO you can add a tag for that too.

Comment: Your "output with decimals" is the representation of a large number using scientific notation. E9 means "x10^9". So your number there is (rounded) 4.11 * 10 ^ 9. ie: 4,110,515,268. To the extent that this notation has rounded your number to be different than what you expect it to be [ie: if you actually have decimals in your number], this is called a "floating point error".